# Correctly loop and retrieve value in SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to find a correct way to loop and retrieve values in SwiftyJSON.
Please see comments in the code below.

```
audioReq.executeWithResultBlock({
            response in
            let json = JSON(response.json)
            for (key, subJson) in json {
                if let title = subJson[key].string {   //<-- Loop does not work! 
                    println(title)                    //     It prints nothing!
                }
            }

            if let title = json[0]["first_name"].string {
                println(title)                                  //<-- Works
            }
            if let title = json[0]["last_name"].string {
                println(title)                                 //<-- Works
            }
            if let title = json[0][1].string {
                println(title)                        //<-- Does not work!
            }                                         //  Prints nothing!

            if let title = json[0]["id"].string {
                println(title)                        //<-- Does not work!
            }                                         //  Prints nothing!
            println(response.json)
                                   },
            errorBlock: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                println(error.localizedDescription)
        })
```

Contents of response.json:

```
(
        {
        "first_name" = "Dachnik";
        id = 12345678;               // should be  "id" = 12345678
        "last_name" = "Neudachnik";
    }
)
```

Comment: The JSON response seems to be formatted incorrectly...

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using array instead of dictionary. What should work is

```
for (key, subJson) in json[0] {
    if let title = subJson[key].string {   //<-- Loop does not work! 
        println(title)                    //     It prints nothing!
    }
}
```

If you have multiple users, then you should do something like (don't have MAC here)

```
for dict in json {
    // go through dictionary elements here: first_name, last_name, id
    // you can use same for loop as above
}
```

Comment: I have contacted the developer responsible for the SDK I am using and he said that is fine for the server response to look like that :( It is not usable as a JSON, because of improper formtaing, but it can still be used with the help of NSDictionary.